# Como quebrar uma string

Tags: delphi-7

Quero quebrar uma string no Delphi antigo (pré-Embarcadero). Eu adoraria poder fazer algo do tipo:

```
function Quebra (input: String; separador: String) : Array of String
var resultado: Array of String
begin
    resultado := input.Split(separador);
    return resultado;
end;
```

Mas aparentemente o método `Split` não existia nos tempos heróicos.

Eu pesquisei no Google e [na nossa matriz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625707/split-a-string-into-an-array-of-strings-based-on-a-delimiter). Mas não encontrei nenhuma resposta civilizadamente curta, i.e.: não gostaria de ter que [escovar bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10232862/2263584) só pra fazer algo que deveria ser tão simples e que outras linguagens já tinham décadas antes do Delphi. É possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algo assim?

```
function Quebra (input: String; separador: String) : TStringList
var resultado: TStringList
begin
    resultado := TStringList.Create;
    resultado.Delimiter := separador;
    resultado.DelimitedText := input;
    return resultado;
end;
```

Fonte:
http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TStringList

Answer (score 3):

Para o caso de querer utilizar uma matriz contendo String's, você também pode utilizar da seguinte maneira, caso queira:

```
Type
  aStrings = Array Of String; // Utilize um Tipo de Matriz para Parâmetros de Rotinas

...

Procedure Quebra( Input: String; Separador: Char; Var ListString: AStrings );
Var
   Resultado: TStringList;
   idLst: Integer;
Begin
   // Previne que exista elementos maiores que Resultado.Count
   // uma vez que se trata de variável externa.
   SetLength( ListString, 0 );

   Resultado := TStringList.Create;
   Try
      // Utilizada apenas um caractere como delimitador
      Resultado.Delimiter := Separador;
      Resultado.DelimitedText := Input;

      // Define novo tamanho para a matriz
      SetLength( ListString, Resultado.Count );

      For idLst := 0 To Pred( Resultado.Count ) Do
         ListString[ idLst ] := Resultado[ idLst ];
   Finally
      Resultado.Free;
   End;

End;
```

OU

```
Procedure Quebra( Input: String; Separador: String; Var ListString: AStrings );
Var
   Resultado: TStringList;
   idLst: Integer;
Begin
   // Previne que exista elementos maiores que Resultado.Count
   // uma vez que se trata de variável externa.
   SetLength( ListString, 0 );

   Resultado := TStringList.Create;
   Try
      // Possibilita que seja utilizada uma sequencia de caracteres como delimitador
      Resultado.Text := StringReplace( Input, Separador, #13#10, [ rfReplaceAll ] );

      // Define novo tamanho para a matriz
      SetLength( ListString, Resultado.Count );

      For idLst := 0 To Pred( Resultado.Count ) Do
         ListString[ idLst ] := Resultado[ idLst ];
   Finally
      Resultado.Free;
   End;

End;
```

Quanto a utilização, fica assim:

```
Var
   aTexto: aStrings;
Begin
   Quebra( 'Como quebrar uma string', ' ', aTexto );
   //aTexto[ 0 ] = 'Como'
   //aTexto[ 1 ] = 'quebrar'
   //aTexto[ 2 ] = 'uma'
   //aTexto[ 3 ] = 'string'
End;
```